# Internet connection fails in Ubuntu on VirtualBox when virtual machine is created from "Import appliance"

Tags: ubuntu, networking, virtualbox

I have installed Ubuntu Server 9.10 in a virtual machine in VirtualBox, then I made a cope/clone and exported it with "Export appliance" so I can create many cloned virtual machines.

But when I try to import an appliance, everthing seams to be fine with the Ubuntu except that it can't connect to Internet and doesn't get an IP-address. The machine is used in Bridged mode. And it doesn't help to change to NAT-mode either.

The machine that I cloned seams to work fine, and get an IP address.

How to fix this? Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved on ServerFault: https://serverfault.com/questions/30889/virtualbox-cloned-ubuntu-server-network-error/30893#30893

`rm /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` and then reboot.

Comment: I would not blindly delete this file, instead remove the offending lines in it.

Answer (score 1):

hmm. i'd look at lshw and check if the name of the network device has changed, and edit /etc/network/interfaces to match if it has. then ifup  - no need for a reboot

Comment: i think the point is that the cloning has given the machine a separate MAC address, so udev's given the NIC a new device name since the MAC didn't match.  removing the *70-persistent-net.rules* removes the old MAC; it's recreated on restart with the new MAC.  if you don't remove the file, tho, the old MAC never gets removed.