# What is the recommended way of cloning virtual machines in VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

Is there any recommended way of cloning virtual machines in VirtualBox? I would like to install an Operating System and then make several clones of that one. I have tried with `export` and `import appliance` but I have got some problems doing it that way. See [Internet connection fails in Ubuntu on VirtualBox when virtual machine is created from “Import appliance”](https://superuser.com/questions/121804/internet-connection-fails-in-ubuntu-on-virtualbox-when-virtual-machine-is-created)

I have now also tried `VBoxManage clonehd`, but I got the same problems as when I exported the appliance. The machine gets no IP-address.

Comment: _but I have got some problems doing it that way._ Details? Please quote error messages. Are the problems with simultaneous usage of the cloned images?

Comment: Details about that problem is in the other question, follow the link. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have used the vboxmanage command to clone drives and it has worked fine for me. If you are running the machine in bridged network mode on the same machine, perhaps the two virtual machines are competing for the network card somehow.

I would troubleshoot like this:

- Let the original virtual machine
  configuration use the new hard drive file, and try to boot only that machine.
  (Change the "storage" and use the
  new, cloned disk image instead of the
  original one).

If this works then you
   know it's not a problem with the
   virtual drive, it's the virtual
   machine config.

If that turns out to be the case you can try this:

- Verify that the two virtual machines
  have different MAC addresses (Under
  "advanced" in the network settings
  for the VM).
- Let both machines run in NAT mode.
- Enable an extra network card on the new virtual machine and see if that gets an IP-address.

Answer (score 1):

If the Import/Export option doesn't work, investigate the command-line options available with the VBoxManager 
command. 
[This link](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-control-virtual-machines-virtualbox-using-vboxmanage.html) may prove useful.

Comment: Thanks, `VBoxManage clonehd` seams to be the right thing to do. But I still got the network problem, but that is however solved in my other question.

Answer (score 0):

I found [an article on cloning and copying VirtualBox machines](http://srackham.wordpress.com/cloning-and-copying-virtualbox-virtual-machines/) which worked fine for me..

Answer (score 0):

The way I make copies of a VirtualBox VHD is by using CloneZilla, a live CD used for cloning and imaging disks.

In a nutshell:

1. Install your OS the way you want it.
2. Download the CloneZilla ISO and mount it in the virtual machine
3. Attach a virtual hard disk of the same size or larger as a second disk in the virtual machine.
4. Clone the primary disk to the secordary
5. If needed, resize the partition.

You should be able to find a tutorial how to do this on the VirtualBox forums.